# Plug-in Executing 4 Times for a Single Event

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

What could possibly cause a plug-in to execute 4 times from a single event?
The plug-in has been registered on-retrieve of Case and fires 4 times for a single Retrieve.

```cs
        protected void ExecutePostCaseRetrieve(LocalPluginContext localContext)
        {
        if (localContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
        }
        
        // TODO: Implement your custom Plug-in business logic.
        IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;
        QueryByAttribute query = new QueryByAttribute("resource");
        query.Attributes.AddRange("name");
        query.Values.AddRange("Employee");
        EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
        Guid employee = result.Entities[0].Id;
        QueryScheduleRequest scheduleRequest = new QueryScheduleRequest
        {
            ResourceId = employee,
            Start = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(),
            End = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().AddMonths(1),
            TimeCodes = new TimeCode[] { TimeCode.Available }
        };
        QueryScheduleResponse schedule = (QueryScheduleResponse)service.Execute(scheduleRequest);
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
        if (today.Date.Equals(schedule.TimeInfos[0].Start.Value.Date)) // today is a working day
        {
            service.Create(new Lead { FirstName = today.Hour.ToString() });
        }
        else // just escalate from beginning of next working day
            service.Create(new Lead { FirstName = schedule.TimeInfos[0].Start.Value.ToLocalTime().ToString(), LastName=schedule.TimeInfos[0].End.Value.ToLocalTime().ToString() });
```

[image]

I have tried synchronous and asynchronous, the same thing happens.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the registration please

Comment: What are the exact messages in the *Context* if you log them to a file? I suspect that it's **you** who triggers the plugins when you create (an other) entity.

Comment: What criteria are you using to judge that it executes 4 times?

Comment: @glosrob The plugin creates a Lead (for testing); 4 leads are created instead of 1. There is no loop or anything: service.Create(new Lead {Firstname="TEST"});

Answer (score 1):

Except from a bug being to blame (which I suspect is **not** the case), the only reasonable way to quad-fire a plug in is that you have a call to it from itself. The problem with this answer is that such a setup usually results in an eternal recursion and a poof on the screen.

Speculating regarding the cause, I realize that there are four re-calls in your issue and there are four basic operations of CRUD. May that be a dependency?

EDIT:

As my MVP always says. In such situations, find out *where* it happens before you try to explain *why* it happens. In some cases, he's right.

So, this is what I'd do in this case.

The term *magic*will in the following list mean this set of operations: remove all instances of *Case* and *Lead*, create a single one of *Case* and see how many instance of *Lead* there are.

1. Remove all plugins. Do the *magic*.
2. Register an "empty" plugin on *Create* for *Case*. Do the *magic*.
3. Add creation of a *Lead* to the plugin (`Service.Create(new Entity("case"));`
   ). Do the *magic*.
4. Copy/paste stuff from your existing code to the new. Do the *magic*.

You can try that for a totally new installation, too, to guarantee that there's no other software that collides. There's a free 30-day trial. I've got about 10 different trials at any given time.   :)

Comment: The plug-in is only registered on retrieve of Case and it is creating a Lead. When it is registered on RetrieveMultiple it fires only once.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a year old, but I ran into the same issue with another plugin triggering my first plugin. The crm service actually has a depth property you can use to figure out how many actions have triggered before this one.

putting something like this before the code to be executed can solve this problem.

```
if (context.depth > 1 ){
return;
}
```